# Git: How to copy bitbucket master to a local branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to copy master of bitbucket to a branch in my local machine. The master of my local machine is different code and I don't want to change it for some reasons. Should I do first checkout in my local branch and then do `git pull remote master`? Is this all right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply fetch and then checkout that remote tracking branch under a different name:

```
git remote add bitbucket /url/of/bitbucket/repo
git fetch bitbucket
git checkout -b anewBranch --track bitbucket/master
```

That way, your local `master` is untouched, and you have the bitbucket `master` checked out in its own local branch.

Answer (score 0):

Your local `master` will get modified. What you can do is create & checkout a branch like `my_master` and commit your current changes to it.

Then you can `pull master` but that will by default `merge` with your local `master`. You can then do a merge yourself with changes from `my_master`.

Optionally, after creating `my_master`, you could do only a `fetch` and then do a merge yourself with the changes you want. (`pull` = `fetch + merge` sort of).